# Rsync became slow from one specific router

Tags: rsync, router

I have an ubuntu server. Up until about a week ago, I could rsync to it with an upspeed of 18-22 mb/s. Now, however, I get about 30kb/s.

I have tested multiple machines, and they all exhibit this problem. Furthermore, if I rsync from a different network, it works normally, 18-22mb/s. I know this means the problem is with my router or ISP, but I don't know anywhere else to ask. Power cycling the router did not help, and I cannot imagine any change that would have occured to cause this. I'm at a loss.